# How to store set of long char strings to search for long char string key

Tags: search-algorithms

I have a set of several thousand strings of max length 1024 (containing all visible ASCII chars plus space) I need to store to make it fast to search for an exact match of a key.  What is the best algorithm to store the set and to search for a match?

Comment: Perhaps a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the distribution of the keys ?

Answer (score 1):

A hash-table seems a good option. As the keys are long, collisions should be minimized. So don't fear to be generous on the number of buckets (low fill factor).

Unless your strings have long prefixes in common, a sequential search among the colliding strings will not be very costly (early termination in case of mismatch).

If there are long common prefixes, you can do the comparison backward from the end, or even from... the middle.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a [suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) (or suffix tree).  That allows very fast searching for a match.

Given multiple words, there is a standard way to compute a suffix array (or suffix tree) associated with them: concatenate them, separated by some separator.  For instance, if the words are APPLE, CAT, and DOG, you obtain the string APPLE\$CAT\$DOG\$.  Then, compute the suffix array/tree of that single long string.

Comment: According to the link you provided, a suffix array is used to find a substring of a single string.  Are you suggesting I consider the set of several thousand longish strings as a single string and compute all suffixes on the set?

Comment: @DaveS., see edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that pops to my mind is to do a hash on the strings, store the hashes in some efficient tree and the hits as a list. A suitable hash algorithm might decrease the number of actual string searches. Additionally given a good hash algorithm you might only need to check a few chars.

On second thought, there are two further things to consider when selecting algorithm.

1. What is the balance between searching, adding and deleting? I assumed that searching is a lot more common that adding/deleting.
2. Where does the strings differ? If they in average all are about the same length and all start with a few hundred characters the same in the beginning it might influence your choice.